# PHP: finding, replacing, shortening, and prettifying user links with <a> tags, ellipses, and link icons

Tags: php, url, prettify

When a user enters a URL, e.g. `http://www.google.com`, I would like to be able to **parse that text using PHP**, **find any links**, **and replace them** with `<a>` tags that include the original URL as an `HREF`.

In other words, `http://www.google.com` will become

`<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`

I'd like to be able to do this for all URLs of these forms (with `.com` interchangeable with any TLD):

```
http://www.google.com
www.google.com
google.com
docs.google.com
```

What's the most performant way to do this? I could try writing some really fancy regex, but I doubt that's the best method available to me.

For bonus points, I'd also like to prepend `http://` to any URL lacking it, and strip the display text itself down to something of the form `http://www.google.com/reallyLongL...` and display an external link icon afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got this working exactly the way I want here:**

```
<?php

$input = <<<EOF
http://www.example.com/
http://example.com
www.example.com
http://iamanextremely.com/long/link/so/I/will/be/trimmed/down/a/bit/so/i/dont/mess
/up/text/wrapping.html
EOF;

  function trimlong($match)
  {
    $url = $match[0];
    $display = $url;
    if ( strlen($display) > 30 ) {
      $display = substr($display,0,30)."...";
    }
    return '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$display.' <img src="http://static.goalscdn.com/img/external-link.gif" height="10" width="11" /></a>';
  }

$output = preg_replace_callback('#(http://|www\\.)[^\\s<]+[^\\s<,.]#i',
                                 array($this,'trimlong'),$input);

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to find links in the format domain.com is going to be a pain in the butt. It would require keeping track of all TLDs and using them in the search.if you didnt the end of the last sentence i typed and the beginning of this sentence would be a link to http://search.if. Even if you did .in is a valid TLD and a common word.

I'd recommend telling your users they have to begin links with `www.` or `http://` then write a simple regex to capture them and add the links.

Comment: Great point about the TLDs. That would obviously be impossible to do well.

Answer (score 1):

> www.google.com

This is not a URL, it's a hostname. It's generally not a good idea to start marking up bare hostnames in arbitrary text, because in the general case any word or sequence of dot-separated words is a perfectly valid hostname. That means you up with horrible hacks like looking for leading `www.` (and you'll get questions like “why can I link to `www.stackoverflow.com` but not `stackoverflow.com`?”) or trailing TLDs (which gets more and more impractical as more new TLDs are introduced; “why can I like to ncm.com but not `ncm.museum`?”), and you'll often mark up things that aren't supposed to be links.

> I could try writing some really fancy regex

Well I can't see how you'd do it *without* regex.

The trick is coping with markup. If you can have `<`, `&` and `"` characters in the input, you mustn't let them into HTML output. If your input is plain text, you can do that by calling `htmlspecialchars()` before applying a simple replacement on a pattern like that in nico's answer.

(If the input already contains markup, you've got problems and you'd probably need an HTML parser to determine which bits are markup to avoid adding more markup inside of. Similarly, if you're doing more processing after this, inserting more tags, those steps are may have the same difficulty. In ‘bbcode’-like languages this often leads to bugs and security problems.)

Another problem is trailing punctuation. It's common for people to put a full stop, comma, close bracket, exclamation mark etc after a link, which aren't supposed to be part of the link but which are actually valid characters. It's useful to strip these off and not put them in the link. But then you break Wiki links that end in `)`, so maybe you want to not treat `)` as a trailing character if there's a `(` in the link, or something like that. This sort of thing can't be done in a simple regex replace, but you can in a replacement callback function.

Comment: All good points. At the moment I run `strip_tags('<b><i><br><br/><br /><ol><ul><li>')` when users post, so `<a>` tags aren't allowed.

Comment: Any tag can have markup inside it, eg `<b title="blah http://something... blah">`; if you put an `<a>` inside that attribute you'd have a big mess. Anyway, `strip_tags` is not at all safe; there is almost never a good reason to use it. A user can do something like `<b onmouseover="stealcookies()">` or whatever. Don't let users post HTML. Instead let them post plain text and encode with `htmlspecialchars()`, and `nl2br()` if necessary

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know XSS can occur within any tags. But I have content from a WYSIWYG editor that includes `<b>` and `<i>` tags. I've tried looking around `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()` to see how to escape this, but I don't see how I can escape the output to avoid XSS but still have the tags work properly.

Comment: [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). But, if you are dealing with HTML in general you still have the possibility of things that look like URLs appearing in markup, in which case you cannot use a simple regex replace to mark up links. Given your small range of desired markup possibilities it would seem more sensible to use a [lightweight markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language) of some sort rather than HTML. Then users can enter text with simple tricks like `*italic*` for *italic*, like on SO, and not have to worry about tag-matching and manual `<br>`.

Comment: I strongly second the use of HTML Purifier (does not help with your question, but it's a very good tool anyways)

Answer (score 1):

[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) has a [built-in linkify function](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#AutoFormat.Linkify) to save you all the headaches.

It's other features are also simply too useful to pass up if you're dealing with any kind of user input that you also have to display.

Comment: Awesome. I just started using HTML Purifier not long ago, so this is absolutely great.

Answer (score 0):

Not so fancy regexps that should work

```
/\b(https?:\/\/[^\s+\"\<\>]+)/ig
/\b(www.[^\s+\"\<\>]+)/ig
```

Note that the last two would be impossible to do correctly as you cannot distinguish google.com from something like this.Where I finish one sentence and don't put a space after the full stop.

As for shortening the URLs, having your URL in `$url`:

```
if (strlen($url) > 20) // Or whatever length you like
   {
   $shortURL = substr($url, 0, 20)."&hellip;";
   }
else
   {
   $shortURL = $url;
   }

echo '<a href="'.$url.'" >'.$shortURL.'</a>';
```

Comment: Nice. I also posted an answer (apologies, but wanted comments on it). If you wouldn't mind, I'd love to see what you think of that, especially appending the ellipsis using the regexp (since there's no way that I can think of to apply `strlen()` with that option).

Comment: @Josh Smith: No need to apologize! :) Anyway... your question is good but unfortunately I do not have an answer for it, sorry! Maybe someone more knowledgeable in regexp than me can answer you!

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/view/markup_urls

```
function markup_urls ($text)
{
  // split the text into words
  $words = preg_split('/([\s\n\r]+)/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
  $text = "";

  // iterate through the words
  foreach($words as $word) {

    // chopword = the portion of the word that will be replaced
    $chopword = $word;
    $chopword = preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z0-9]*/', '', $chopword);

    if ($chopword <> '') {
      // linkword = the text that will replace chopword in the word
      $linkword='';

      // does it start with http://abc. ?
      if (preg_match('/^(http:\/\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_]{2,}.*/', $chopword)) {

        $chopword = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\/]*$/', '', $chopword);
        $linkword = '<a href="'.$chopword.'" target="blank">'.$chopword.'</a>';

      // does it equal abc.def.ghi ?
      } else if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\/.*)?/', $chopword)) {

        $chopword = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\/]*$/', '', $chopword);
        $linkword = '<a href="http://'.$chopword.'" target="blank">'.$chopword.'</a>';

      // does it start with abc@def.ghi ?
      } else if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{2,}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}.*/', $chopword)) {

        $chopword = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]*$/', '', $chopword);
        $linkword = '<a href="mailto:'.$chopword.'">'.$chopword.'</a>';

      }

      // replace chopword with linkword in word (if linkword was set)
      if ($linkword <> '') {
        $word = str_replace($chopword, $linkword, $word);
      }
    }

    // append the word
    $text = $text.$word;
  }

  return $text;
}
```